# Runtime of the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o, largenumber

I need to find run-time of this algorithm as a function of k, where k is number of bits in n.

```
def ff(n):
    x = 0
    while ((x+1)*(x+1) <= n):
        x+=1
    return x
```

I understand that, the run-time is O(sqrt(n)), if n is a small number, how do I convert it to a function of k? I don't need the direct answer, explanation would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: O(sqrt(n)) is a statement about asymptotic behaviour and says nothing about runtime when n is a small number.

Answer (score 0):

if I am not mistaken then upper bound is

- `k=log2(n)`
- `n=2^k`
- so:
- `T(sqrt(n)) -> T(sqrt(2^k)) -> T((2^k)^0.5) -> T((2^(k/2))`
- sorry for the T confusion but where I am from for runtime is used to use T instead of O
- O is reserved for complexity (Omega)

PS.

- you should measure the runtime because on modern machines
- the code is very different from what the execution of it looks like
- due to multiple pipelines, caches, HW capabilities ,etc ...
- especially for finite/low n